# efficient OpenGL texture loading gxbase

Tags: opengl, loading, textures

Using OpenGL and using GxBase I am loading my textures.

```
if (Image.Load("ball.jpg"))
{
    Image.FlipY();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, MyTexture[0]);
    Image.gluBuild2DMipmaps();
}
```

How do I make sure that I don't load the same texture twice?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used GxBase, but I'd just maintain a map that maps filenames to texture ids (strings to GLuints)

When you go to load a new one, look in the map first and if it's there, return the texture id instead of loading it again. Otherwise load it, and then save the generated texture id

Try something like:

```
std::map<std::string,GLuint> textures;
...

// Inside your method to load textures:

if (textures.count(textureName) == 0)
{
    // load texture
    textures[textureName] = // the GLuint texture id
}
else
{
    return textures[textureName];
}
```

Comment: any chance you have the code snippets for that or guide me to tutorials for that? thanks